# How to compute this chain rule process for higher derivative using a software

Tags: derivatives, dynamical-systems, programming

Consider the following system:
$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x}_1 &= -x^3_1 + 2x^3_2 \tag{1} \\
\dot{x}_2 &= -2x_1x^2_2 \tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
The Lyapunov function and its first derivative are 
$$
\begin{align}
V(x) &= \frac{1}{2}x^2_1 + \frac{1}{2}x^2_2 \tag{3} \\
\dot{V}(x) &= -x^4_1 \tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Don't worry about how $\dot{V}(x)$ is obtained. Now I need to compute the second derivative of $V(x)$ which is:
$$
\begin{align}
\ddot{V}(x) &= -4x^3_1\dot{x}_1 \tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
From Eq(1)(5), we get:
$$
\begin{align}
\ddot{V}(x) &= -4x^3_1\dot{x}_1 \\
&= -4x^3_1(-x^3_1 + 2x^3_2) \\
&= 4x^6_1 - 8x^3_1x^3_2 \tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
Now to get the third derivative, we can do:
$$
\begin{align}
\dddot{V}(x) &= 24x^5_1\dot{x}_1 - 8\Big[3x^2_1\dot{x}_1x^3_2 + 3x^3_1x^2_2\dot{x}_2  \Big]     
\end{align} 
$$
The process goes in this manner until $x_2$ isolated. Is there any program which can do this tedious calculation for higher derivatives? Matlab is welcome since I have an access to it. Other online softwares are welcome as well as long as they are free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wolfram Cloud](https://www.wolframcloud.com/) will help you with this

First define the system of equations

```
Clear[t,x1,x2];
dx1 = -x1[t]^3 + 2x2[t]^3;
dx2 = -2x1[t]x2[t]^2;

V=x1[t]^2/2 + x2[t]^2/2;
```

And now build the recursive list

```
nmax = 2
NestList[(D[#,t]/.{x1'[t] -> dx1, x2'[t] -> dx2}//FullSimplify)&, V, nmax]
```

This will give you a list of the form

$$
\{V, V^{(1)}, \cdots, V^{(n_\max)} \}
$$

where $V^{(k)} = {\rm d}^k V/{\rm d} t^k$

[image]

which is exactly what you have in your post. Change the value of `nmax` to change the number of iterations

Comment: that was insane. Thank you so much.

Comment: @CroCo Happy to help

Answer (score 1):

In Matlab, you define a vector of variables and a vector of right-hand sides, say,

```
x = [x1; x2];
f= [-x1^3+2*x2^3;−2*x1*x2^2];
```

and compute the derivative of $V(x_1,x_2)$ w.r.t. $f$ iteratively:

```
D1V=jacobian(V,x)*f;
D2V=jacobian(D1V,x)*f;
```

etc. You can use Matlab's *simplify* if the expressions become very bulky.